# Access to webcam c# Windows 8.1 permission

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1, webcam

How to get access to webcan in c# and Metro app(windows 8.1 store app). After start app i see somthing like that "This application need permission to use camera". I try to add permission in cam setting, but ther's no way to find my aplication. In outhers aplication system allways ask for use cam.
Example code:

```
{          
        CameraCaptureUI view = new CameraCaptureUI();
        view.VideoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIVideoFormat.Mp4;
        StorageFile file = await view.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Video);

        IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        captured.SetSource(fileStream, "ASD");
}
```

Comment: you should add webcam capability to your app via Package.appxmanifest.